# Performance: Calculating Div Positions

Tags: javascript, html

I set up at test case on jsperf here: http://jsperf.com/rect-vs-offsettopmsa

Now a lot of the results there seem intuitive and make sense, however there is one thing that bothers me regarding ScrollTop and OffsetTop.

Why is it that ScrollTop is almost 3-4x faster than OffsetTop if they are both DOM Element properties? Especially since OffsetTop is also only a read-only property according to the msdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop

Comment: They don't measure the same thing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

Comment: Maybe it is because `.scrollTop` will always return `0`, but `.offsetTop` always returns `5000` in your test. So, it may be that accessing a variable which value is 0 is faster?

Comment: Possibly, it depends on the implementation. My point is, comparing the 2 don't really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure — you'll have to examine source code to be sure. But the obvious reason for the offsetTop poorer performance is that it is simply more complicated to compute.

To calculate Element.scrollTop browser just needs to explore the Element you asking for — it can get all the input data it needs just from it.

But to calculate Element.offsetTop you need to calculate the element's position AND it's parent's — and then compare them to get the relative position. Hence more time needed to perform it.

[Here](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#dom-htmlelement-offsettop) you can find a description of how Element.offsetTop works according to spec.

> If the element is the HTML body element or does not have any associated CSS layout box return zero and terminate this algorithm.
>
> If the offsetParent of the element is null return the y-coordinate of the top border edge of the first CSS layout box associated with the element, relative to the initial containing block origin, ignoring any transforms that apply to the element and its ancestors, and terminate this algorithm.
>
> Return the result of subtracting the y-coordinate of the top padding edge of the first CSS layout box associated with the offsetParent of the element from the y-coordinate of the top border edge of the first CSS layout box associated with the element, relative to the initial containing block origin, ignoring any transforms that apply to the element and its ancestors.

So yeah, even if it looks like a simple property, it still can trigger some calculations on the element.

UPDATED:

It looks that my answer is still incorrect because of this interface declared in the same spec:

```
partial interface HTMLElement {
  readonly attribute Element? offsetParent;
  readonly attribute long offsetTop;
  readonly attribute long offsetLeft;
  readonly attribute long offsetWidth;
  readonly attribute long offsetHeight;
};
```

So, yes, both this properties are readOnly, so the fact that one is 3 times faster then other doesn't make much sense. Ignore what I've written earlier.

Comment: Yes, but `offsetTop` looks like a member, not a method. It is `.offsetTop` , not `.offsetTop()` which would imply that more calculations are done when accessing the method.